# Swift: Thread issue with core data

Tags: swift, multithreading, core-data

I have an app where I call an endpoint to retrieve a list of products from an API:

```
var productList = [Product]

private func retrieveProducts() {
    API.client.call(.products, expecting: [Product].self) { (result, products) in
        switch result {
        case .failure:
            print("Unable to retrieve products")
        case .success:
            guard let productResponse = products else { return }
            for product in productResponse {
                productList.append(product)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NB: we use a helper class for the API call, .products injects the correct url.

Product class:

```
class Product: Codable {
    let id: String
    let name: String?
}
```

These products are then used to populate a drop down. Now what I am trying to do is to make these available offline, so essentially the first time the app is launched I want to save the products to core data, and then on subsequent launches we just retrieve the stored list.

So I have build a core data model with an entity entitled ProductCD and have changed my retrieveProducts method as follows:

```
private func saveProductsToCD() {
    API.client.call(.products, expecting: [Product].self) { (result, products) in
        switch result {
        case .failure:
            print("Unable to retrieve products")
        case .success:
            guard let productResponse = products else { return }
            for product in productResponse {
                product.mapToCoreData()
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.appDelegate.saveContext()
                self.getSavedProducts()
            }
        }
    }
}

internal func getSavedProducts() {
// First I attempt to retrieve the list from core data

    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request: NSFetchRequest<ProductCD> = ProductCD.fetchRequest()
    do {
        productsList = try context.fetch(request)
    } catch {
        print("Error fetching data from context \(error)")
    }
 // If no data available in core data I call the method above to hit the 
 // products endpoint and save to core data, then I retrieve the products

    if productList.count == 0 {
        self.saveProductsToCD()
    }
}
```

I added the mapToCoreData method on the Product class:

```
class Product: Codable {
    let id: String
    let name: String?
    
    internal func mapToCoreData() {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let storedProduct = ProductCD(context: context)
        
        storedProduct.id = self.id
        storedProduct.name = self.name ?? ""
    }
}
```

So, whilst this is kind of working there are issues. The data is being stored and recalled, however due to threading issues (I guess) I'm getting a warning and some occasional crashes:

1- warning: on my Product class I get the following warning:

```
UIApplication.delegate must be used from main thread only
```

I tried wrapping the call in DispatchQueue.Main.async but I still get the message.

2- Sometimes on loading, my app crashes with this message:

```
Thread 9: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
```

On this line in my Product class:

```
let storedProduct = ProductCD(context: context)
```

This error is occurring when I'm typing in the textfield which essentially attempts to retrieve the core database.

This crash only happens occasionally on launch so I'm sure it's a threading issue but not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: Put `for product in productResponse { product.mapToCoreData() }` in the `DispatchQueue.main.async{ here }` too.

Comment: Perfect, and so simple. Thanks very much!

Comment: The above will do for a demo, but if you are developing a real app, I suggest looking at parts 11-17 of this tutorial: https://github.com/aliakhtar49/Mastering-in-CoreData because blocking main thread with core data work from background thread is not a good design